# Partially funded PhD in Germany

Tags: phd, funding, germany

I have been offered a PhD position in a German institution, however,  it is not a job or fully funded position. While I plan to apply for a full scholarship moving forward,  just in case, is it possible to pursue a PhD besides another part-time job?

Would it be wise to accept the offer regardless? And if otherwise,  what kind of inconveniences one might encounter in this situation?

Comment: This needs more detail for us to be able to answer it. What kind of partial funding is this?

Comment: It is fairly common to offer a part-time position (50% to 60%) for a PhD student. The (unfair) idea is that you do paid work for 50% to 60% of the week on some project, maybe some teaching, and you use the remainder of the week to work on your dissertation. If you are lucky those paid tasks align well with your dissertation project. The idea is definitely *not* that you do a part-time job for the remaining 40% to 50%. If you don't like that, and I can see why you would not, then don't take that job.

Comment: Maarten Buis is right - the idea of a "part time position" is that you get a part of the money you get for a 100% position, and you have the guarantee that in the remaining fraction, you can work in a concentrated way on your PhD. *But* there is the expectation that also a good part of the actual working hours you can spend on activities related to your PhD. However, there is also grant acquisition, teaching, and the like to be done while holding these positions. Doing another part time job on the side is normally unrealistic and may be against the visa terms anyway.

Comment: are you an EU citizen? do you need a visa to live or to live and work in Germany?)

Comment: Please give much more information. This is hugely dependent on the field. For instance, in psychology it is extremely common to have 50% positions, but the expectation is that you indeed work full time. (And while the 50% salary is not something to get rich off, you *can* live on it without going into debt as a single person. If you have dependents, this is another important piece of information.) In contrast, fewer positions in computer science are less than 100%, because people have more other options. This is just supply and demand in action. Please give more details.

Answer (score 5):

If you get a scolarship (it seems so, since you mention it is not a job) you are considered a student and finding a job can be hard (do you need a visa to work in Germany? with the scolarship you may get a student visa, then you cannot legally work).

The ugly part of the scolarship is thay it is not a working contract. So you still have to figure out all the bureaucracy for the health insurance (tedious and potentially very expensive), to figure out how to get reductions and what and how are you effectively covered for (yes, everyone will tell you it is quite standard, that there are laws etcetc ... usually no one "local" of them had no first-hand nor even second-hand experience of things gone wrong, which happens especially among people not speaking german and not having any friends speaking german).

Additionally, the scolarship does not allow you to enter into the unemployment system when the scolarship runs out. Please remember that is socially accepted and absolutely the norm to think that the last 3 months of your PhD can be performed while on unemployment money... and usually the last 3 months turn out in being 9 months or even 1/1.5 years. Yes, people do that much of their PhD while on unemployment money: the average (not-existing) german will tell you that those are still public money, like research money, but with a different label, so it is totally ok to be on the social insurance money while performing research that benefits your supervisor's CV.

All in all, I would rationally consider the scolarship good as a bridge solution for 3/6 months, if you have no relocation expenses, if you consider and use it as "seed-money" to be paid while working from home and trying to a secure position.

Otherwise a german scholarship is just a joke, used by institutions and professors to have skilled people cheaply (and if they pay them low, they will show equal consideration for them ...).

Comment: I think you do have a good point that scholarships in Germany have many disadvantage and that positions as an employee are certainly preferrable. But the following points don't match my experience: "*Please remember that is socially accepted and absolutely the norm to think that the last 3 months of your PhD can be performed while on unemployment money*" In my experience, thinking this is not the norm. [...]

Comment: "*Otherwise a german scholarship is just a joke, used by institutions and professors to have skilled people cheaply (and if they pay them low, they will show equal consideration for them ...)*" I received a scholarship during my PhD (but admittedly I got a 25% position in addition to that for most of the time, which made things much easier) and my PhD advisor was extremely considerate and supportive throughout my PhD (and many years after it, until today).

Comment: @JochenGlueck yes, given the nature of this site, we tend to collect all the horror stories, but it is good to remember that by far the most advisors take their job seriously and advice and support their PhD students.

Comment: @JochenGlueck good you had a caring supervisor. Did you ever wonder why you got a 25% position instead of a 30-35% higher scolarship? for the uni/research centre it would have costed the same ...

Comment: @EarlGrey: No, I did not wonder, because the amount of the scholarship was similar as for most PhD scholarships in Germany at that time. The 25% position was unrelated to the scholarship (and came from a different funding source). My advisor had a number of positions allocated for his group (as is common for professors in Germany), and from those he gave me a 25% position. A department can't (or at least shouldn't) arbitrarily reallocate funding from positions to scholarships, because those positions exist to ensure that a certain amount of teaching is done. [...]

Comment: [...] But you seem to indicate that heaving a 35% higher scholarship would have been preferrable to having the 25% position. May I ask why? From a financial point of view the difference would have been rather small (as the 25% position was advantageous regarding the cost of health insurance). Regarding the work load, the position came with a small amount of teaching duty - which I found to be a good thing because it was a nice change from research now and then, because I consider teaching to be quite beneficial for research, and because it gave me teaching practice which was good careerwise.

Comment: So yes, I was indeed really happy with how my PhD went. I had a really good time regarding both research and teaching, I liked my colleagues and my advisor, and my finanical situation was also completely fine. And no, I did not feel exploited or treated badly in any way. (As @MaartenBuis said, there is a lot of selection bias on this website, so I think it's important that we also tell the positive stories.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck "heaving a 35% higher scholarship would have been preferrable to having the 25% position"
I consider it detrimental. But some people sells them as advantageous "look, the PhD candidate gets more money, and the university needs to spend less money!". 
I think scolarships are an unethical way to provide cheap workforce to research, especially in comparison with a proper PhD contract.

Answer (score 4):

These kind of positions do not exist to give you a poor job as a PhD researcher. They exist to give you an academic job *in addition to* you being a PhD researcher.
The expectation here is that working on your PhD happens in the time *not* covered by the job itself. Any overlap between the work and the PhD is your institution being generous, not anything you should count on. Even for the few jobs that have no obligations besides your PhD, the expectation is that you pour at least 100% of your (working?) day into academia.

So while it is formally *possible* to pursue another part-time job, this will cut into the time you spend on your PhD! The primary inconvenience here is that you will have less time for your PhD, which should be the only reason why you would accept such a low-paying job in the first place.
Plus, your institution (i.e. supervisor) has to agree to any side jobs. If they have the choice between someone working only on their PhD versus someone working a sidejob as well, guess who they will prefer?

So make sure the job itself is sufficient for you. However, there are many kinds of part-time positions so this really depends on what exactly you are offered.
The base pay for PhD is not all that bad and even at 50% you should be able to easily cover living costs for yourself. However, the 25% and lower offered in some domains are usually only feasible with another source of income, such as family supporting you.
If you are not familiar with the German work system, make sure what you have is an offer for actual employment and not a scholarship. The former gives you health insurance and some other important perks; the latter requires jumping some bureaucratic hoops to turn into a benefit and has a lot of downsides otherwise.
Definitely make sure to find out the norm in your domain. While there are no fixed rules, most domains have a de-facto standard since funding comes from similar sources and institutions compete at least somewhat. This usually means a set work fraction and specific duties (e.g. CS has 100% with teaching duties or 75% without). Finding this out let's you gauge whether you are being ripped off and if there is any point in looking for a better offer in the first place.

Comment: *"The expectation here is that working on your PhD happens in the time not covered by the job itself. Any overlap between the work and the PhD is your institution being generous*" This is certainly not the standard in my field (pure math).